# Clustering algorithm for multiple feature types

Tags: r, clustering, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, multidimensional-scaling

I'm attempting to conduct a clustering analysis to identify groups of objects that are related to each other. I have to versions of the same data I'm working with. The first consists of the subjects along with a list of features it does and does not have:

[image: Based on Features]

My second version of this data set has the subjects and self-rated scores that range between 1-7 or 1-100 for questions asked about them:

[image: Based on Q's]

My objective with these datasets, individually, was to find out which subjects were most similar to each other based on their included features and the answers to their questions. To do so, I successfully implemented multidimensional scaling for the feature data and factor analysis on the question data.

However, I now have to combine these data sets as such:

[image: Combined]

However, Since MDS with binary data cannot accept ratio data, and factor analysis cannot accept binary data, how would I determine which subjects were most similar to one another based on these features and questions together?

Thanks!

Comment: By merging the two sets by subject, a big matrix of features and questions will result. I agree that the classic multivariate tools such as MDS and PCA don't make sense on the resulting information. However, you can revert to a finite mixture model such as latent class analysis which would create latent partitions of the subjects where, within a partition, subjects are more similar than between partitions. Lots of queries on CV about latent class analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm not at all familiar with latent class analysis in this context. Would you be able to link any useful papers that I could follow to get a grasp on it with my objective in mind? Thanks!

Comment: *Latent Gold* is a relatively inexpensive LCA software from Statistical Innovations. Their website has many expert, academic papers describing the method. https://www.statisticalinnovations.com/publicationsarticles/